# Why is a sequence of random variables not a markov chain?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains, markov-process, bernoulli-distribution

I have a sequence of random variables:  *Y1, Y2, Y3, ....* where *Y1* and *Y2* are both i.i.d. Bernoulli(0.5),

and for all *j* *>=* 3, the following holds:

if min(*Yj-1*, *Yj-2*) = 1, then *Yj* is Bernoulli(2/3), and

if min(*Yj-1*, *Yj-2*) = 0, then *Yj* is Bernoulli(1/3)

Now, I have been trying to work out why *Y1, Y2, Y3, ....* is not a Markov chain.

I used the Markov property to check this.  That is, if this is not a Markov chain, then,

P(*Y3 = 1* | *Y2 = 1, Y1 = 0*) will not be equal to P(*Y3 = 1* | *Y2 = 1*)

I have just taken *Y3, Y2* and *Y1* to be 1, 1 and 0, to calculate the above, as an example to show that it is not a markov chain.  However, I am getting stuck in the interpretation of the model and therefore the calculations I guess.

I get P(*Y3 = 1* | *Y2 = 1, Y1 = 0*) = P(*Y3=1, Y2=1, Y1=0*) / P(*Y2=1, Y1=0*), and

P(*Y3 = 1 | Y2 = 1*) = P(*Y3=1, Y2=1*) / P(*Y2=1*)

Now, to calculate both the conditional probabilities above, I need the joint probabilities.  How should I calculate the joint pmf's P(*Y3=1, Y2=1, Y1=0*) and P(*Y3=1, Y2=1*) ?

Is there anything I am missing, or anywhere I am going wrong with my approach?  Thanks a lot for any help or advice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's analyze the given information and the problem. The terms $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli$(0.5)$, and for $j \geq 3$:

- if $\min(Y_{i-1}, Y_{i-2}) = 1$, then $Y_i$ is Bernoulli$\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$,
- if $\min(Y_{i-1}, Y_{i-2}) = 0$, then $Y_i$ is Bernoulli$\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$.

To prove that $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, \ldots$ is not a Markov chain, it is sufficient to find one instance where the Markov property does not hold. The Markov property states that:

$$P(Y_{n+1} = y | Y_1 = y_1, Y_2 = y_2, \ldots, Y_n = y_n) = P(Y_{n+1} = y | Y_n = y_n)$$

for all $n$ and for all $y, y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n$.

Now, let's calculate $P(Y_3 = 1 | Y_2 = 1, Y_1 = 0)$ and $P(Y_3 = 1 | Y_2 = 1)$.

#### Calculation of $P(Y_3 = 1 | Y_2 = 1, Y_1 = 0)$

Given $Y_2 = 1$ and $Y_1 = 0$, $Y_3$ is Bernoulli$\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$ because $\min(Y_1, Y_2) = 0$. Therefore:

$$P(Y_3 = 1 | Y_2 = 1, Y_1 = 0) = \frac{1}{3}$$

#### Calculation of $P(Y_3 = 1 | Y_2 = 1)$

Now, $P(Y_3 = 1 | Y_2 = 1)$ will have two cases, depending on the value of $Y_1$:

1. If $Y_1 = 0$, $Y_3$ is Bernoulli$\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$, and the probability is $\frac{1}{3}$.
2. If $Y_1 = 1$, $Y_3$ is Bernoulli$\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$, and the probability is $\frac{2}{3}$.

But $Y_1$ is Bernoulli$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$, so each case has a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore:

$$P(Y_3 = 1 | Y_2 = 1) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) + \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right) = \frac{1}{2}$$

So, $P(Y_3 = 1 | Y_2 = 1, Y_1 = 0) \neq P(Y_3 = 1 | Y_2 = 1)$, which confirms that the sequence $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, \ldots$ is not a Markov chain.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!  So when we have j >= 3 and Yj ~ Bernoulli(1/3) if min(Yj-1, Yj-2) =  0, then, it means that P(Y3 = 1 |  min(Y1, Y2) ) = 1/3.  Essentially, what is given in the set up of the model is a conditional probability, which leads to the calculations that follow.  I hope I have understood the set up properly now... thanks again...

Comment: You've understood it correctly. When the model specifies the distribution of Y_j given min(Y_j-1, Y_j-2), it is indeed giving you a conditional probability. Your interpretation is correct:

The probability that Y_3 is 1 given that the minimum of Y_1 and Y_2 is 0 is 1/3.
The probability that Y_3 is 1 given that the minimum of Y_1 and Y_2 is 1 is 2/3.
These probabilities guide the distribution of Y_3 based on the values of Y_1 and Y_2